# Laravel model approach for multiple inner join

Tags: sql, database, laravel, model

I am creating an app for student scheduling. 
In my app i want to fetch only the student schedule which have an id of 1 and have its schedule details.

I have 3 tables: Student_Schedules, Schedules, Schedule_details

The Tables look like this:

**Student_Schedules**: id, schedule_id

**Schedule_details**: id, schedule_id

**Schedules**: id

So this is the Database Query:

```
$schedule = DB::table('Student_Schedules')
        ::join('schedules', 'Student_Schedules.schedule_id', '=', 'schedules.id')
        ->join('schedule_details', 'schedules.id', '=', 'schedule_details.schedule_id')
        ->where('Student_Schedules.id', '=', 1)
        ->get('Student_Schedules.*');
```

Since im not good at laravel eloquent relationships. Is it possible to use model approach of the given query with multiple inner join.
Any help is appreciated :>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Answer to your is question is yes it is possible to use model approach. You are going to need three Eloquent model for your tables.
which are Schedule, StudentSchedule, ScheduleDetail. you can create it with below command:

```
php artisan make:model Schedule
php artisan make:model StudentSchedule
php artisan make:model ScheduleDetail
```

Now in Schedule.php file, create its relationship with StudentSchedule,ScheduleDetail model

```
public function studentSchedule()
{
    return $this->hasMany(StudentSchedule::class, 'schedule_id');
}

public function scheduleDetail()
{
    return $this->hasOne(ScheduleDetail::class, 'schedule_id');
}
```

Now in StudentSchedule.php file create its relationship with Schedule model:

```
public function schedule()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Schedule::class, 'schedule_id');
}
```

and then replace your query with:

```
StudentSchedule::with(['schedule' => function ($query) {
        $query->with('scheduleDetail');
    }])->where('id',1)->first();
```

Here's [a link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships) to understand laravel Eloquent model relationship better.

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

well, I have read your post. With laravel eloquent relationships is very important, it is another feature of laravel, so you can use database model every table or module.The answer follows these:

1. Migrate database table. When you make every model, you can give relations between them.

**example:**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Student_Schedules extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the phone record associated with the user.
     */
    public function Schedules()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Schedules');
    }
}
```

Above example means you don't join 2 tables and use schedule info by using function `Schedules` on `Student_Schedules` model object result

2.And then you can use their relationship model object,

```
$schedule = Student_Schedules ::find(1)->Schedules;
```

More information , let's contact. thanks...

Answer (score 0):

In the laravel use of eloquent relationship is always good in terms of performance and accuracy. You must also use the relationship like as follows -

You have three tables-

1. schedules
2. student schedules - foreign key with schedules
3. schedule details - foreign key with schedules

I assume you have a students table whoose id is put in student schedules table - 
We will have eloquent relationships like

1) Schedule Model

```
public function studentSchedules(){
 return $this->hasMany(StudentSchedule::class,'schedule_id');
}

public function scheduleDetail(){
 return $this->hasMany(ScheduleDetails::class,'schedule_id');
}
```

Now you can use use those relationships in your logics

```
$schedules = Schedule::all(); /** conditional data must be used always */
foreach($schedules as $key => $schedule){
 $schedules[$key]->details = $schedule->scheduleDetail;
 $schedules[$key]->studentDetail = $schedule->studentSchedules;
}
```

and so on you can use other relationships as well. Laravel relationship having more optimized queries so we must prefer the laravel eloquent relationship first.

I hope it will help you